# Using the Scipy cython_blas interface from Cython not working on vectors Mx1 1xN

Tags: scipy, cython, blas

This has to deal with a similar problem here: [Calling BLAS / LAPACK directly using the SciPy interface and Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710838/calling-blas-lapack-directly-using-the-scipy-interface-and-cython) but is different because I'm using the actual code in the SciPy example here `_test_dgemm`: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/cython_blas.pyx which is extremely fast (5x faster than `numpy.dot` when an output matrix is input or 20x faster if not).  It produces no results if Mx1 1xN vectors are passed.  It produces the same values as `numpy.dot` with matrices passed. I've minimized the code since no answers have been posted for clarity.  Here's the `dgemm.pyx.`:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from scipy.linalg.cython_blas cimport dgemm
from cython cimport boundscheck

@boundscheck(False)
cpdef int fast_dgemm(double[:,::1] a, double[:,::1] b, double[:,::1] c, double alpha=1.0, double beta=0.0) nogil except -1:

    cdef:
        char *transa = 'n'
        char *transb = 'n'
        int m, n, k, lda, ldb, ldc
        double *a0=&a[0,0]
        double *b0=&b[0,0]
        double *c0=&c[0,0]

    ldb = (&a[1,0]) - a0 if a.shape[0] > 1 else 1
    lda = (&b[1,0]) - b0 if b.shape[0] > 1 else 1

    k = b.shape[0]
    if k != a.shape[1]:
        with gil:
            raise ValueError("Shape mismatch in input arrays.")
    m = b.shape[1]
    n = a.shape[0]
    if n != c.shape[0] or m != c.shape[1]:
        with gil:
            raise ValueError("Output array does not have the correct shape.")
    ldc = (&c[1,0]) - c0 if c.shape[0] > 1 else 1
    dgemm(transa, transb, &m, &n, &k, &alpha, b0, &lda, a0,
               &ldb, &beta, c0, &ldc)
    return 0
```

Here's a sample test script:

```
import numpy as np;

a=np.random.randn(1000);
b=np.random.randn(1000);
a.resize(len(a),1);
a=np.array(a, order='c');
b.resize(1,len(b)); 
b=np.array(b, order='c');
c = np.empty((a.shape[0],b.shape[1]), float, order='c'); 

from dgemm import _test_dgemm; 
_test_dgemm(a,b,c);
```

And if you want to play with it on Windows with Python 3.5 x64 here's the `setup.py` to build it via the command prompt typing `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc`

```
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np
import os

try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

module = 'dgemm'

ext_modules = [Extension(module, sources=[module + '.pyx'],
              include_dirs=['C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//10//Include//10.0.10240.0//ucrt','C://Program Files (x86)//Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0//VC//include','C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//8.1//Include//shared'],
              library_dirs=['C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//8.1//bin//x64', 'C://Windows//System32', 'C://Program Files (x86)//Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0//VC//lib//amd64', 'C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//8.1//Lib//winv6.3//um//x64', 'C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//10//Lib//10.0.10240.0//ucrt//x64'],
              extra_compile_args=['/Ot', '/favor:INTEL64', '/EHsc', '/GA'],
              language='c++')]

setup(
    name = module,
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [np.get_include(), os.path.join(np.get_include(), 'numpy')]
    )
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Huh, I thought you had to `cdef extern from "blas.h" nogil:` before using `dgemm`. Plus, I don't get why other examples use function pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I see it right, you try to use fortran-routines for arrays with c-memory-layout.

Even if it is obviously known to you, I would like first to elaborate on the row-major-order (c-memory-layout) and the column-major-order (fortran-memory-layout), in order to deduce my answer.

So if we have a `2x3` matrix (i.e. 2 rows and 3 columns) `A`, and store it in some continuous memory we get:

```
row-major-order(A) = A11, A12, A13, A21, A22, A23
col-major-order(A) = A11, A21, A12, A22, A13, A33
```

That means if we get a continuous memory, which represents a matrix in the row-major-order, and interpret it as a matrix in column-major-order we will get quite a different matrix!

However, we we take a look at the transposed matrix `A^t` we can easily see:

```
row-major-order(A) = col-major-order(A^t)
col-major-order(A) = row-major-order(A^t)
```

That means, if we would like to get the matrix `C` in row-major-order as result, the blas-routine should write the transposed matrix `C` in column-major-order (after all this we cannot change) into this very memory. However, `C^t=(AB)^t=B^t*A^t` and `B^t` an `A^t` are the original matrices reinterpreted in column-major-order.

Now, let `A` be a `n x k`-matrix and  `B` a `k x m`-matrix, the call of [dgemm](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468480) routine should be as follows:

```
dgemm(transa, transb, &m, &n, &k, &alpha, b0, &m, a0, &k, &beta, c0, &m)
```

As you can see, you switched some `n` and `m`  in your code.

Comment: Thank you - that worked for the vectors.  I posted an edit to match the syntax.  The C format is intentional as it is being called from NumPy although the underlying libraries are Fortran.  Great explanation by the way.