# How to call JUCE using Cython?

Tags: enums, compilation, cython, juce

At the moment I'm trying to get the JUCE audio framework to work from Cython. As such, I first want to get a small and simple example running by showing an [AlertWindow](https://www.juce.com/doc/classAlertWindow) through the JUCE framework, but at the moment I seem to be having two small problems: 
1. I have a problem with calling an enum from the JUCE framework
2. I don't know how to include the entire framework for compilation and linking.

My setup.py (called with "python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace"):

```
# Cython compile instructions
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize


compile_args = ['-g', '-std=c++11', '-stdlib=libc++']

extensions = [Extension('testb', ['src/JUCE/testb.pyx'],
            extra_compile_args=compile_args,
            include_dirs = ["JUCE/modules"],)]

setup(
    name='My app',
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)
```

My testb.pyx (Problem 1 is here):

```
# distutils: language = c++

cdef extern from "JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h" namespace "juce":
    cdef cppclass AlertWindow:
        AlertWindow(String, String, AlertIconType)

cdef class PyAlertWindow:
    cdef AlertWindow *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new AlertWindow("", "", NoIcon) # Don't know how to call the enum right here
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    @staticmethod
    def showAlertWindow(b):
        print("at least this works")
```

Furthermore I continuously get these type of errors, which are as far as I know caused by the fact that the rest of the framework is not getting compiled and included/linked. How would I do this?

```
ImportError:
dlopen(<project root>/build/lib/testb.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN4juce6StringC1Ev
Referenced from:
<project root>/build/lib/testb.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in <project root>/build/lib/testb.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

*Also, with the --inplace flag, all compiled files get dumped in my main folder, which does not seem very scaleable, especially with larger frameworks. How do I make sure all .so-files end up in  so they are easily referenced? Or are there better ways of dealing with this?*

---

Ok, so with the help of @ead I was able to get a step further. The code now looks as follows:

```
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

compile_args = ['-g', '-std=c++11', '-stdlib=libc++']

extensions = [Extension('testb', ['src/program/testb.pyx'],
                extra_compile_args=compile_args,
                include_dirs = ["JUCE/modules"],
                libraries=["NewProject"], #the name of your library, WHICH MIGHT BE DIFFERENT FROM THE FILENAME!
                library_dirs=["src/program/JuceLibraryCode"] #where your library is placed.

                    )]

setup(
    name='My app',
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)
```

And my Cython file:

```
# testb.pyx
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h":
    cdef cppclass AlertWindow:
        AlertWindow(String, String, AlertIconType, Component*)

    cdef cppclass Component:
        Component()

    cdef cppclass String:
        String(string)

cdef extern from "JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h" namespace    "juce::AlertWindow":
    ctypedef enum AlertIconType:
        NoIcon
        QuestionIcon
        WarningIcon
        InfoIcon

cdef class PyAlertWindow:
    cdef AlertWindow *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new AlertWindow(String(""), String(""), AlertIconType(NoIcon), NULL)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
```

And the example is now compiling fine. However, when I import the resulting package I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(<project root>/testb.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _CGAffineTransformIdentity
  Referenced from: <project root>/testb.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in <project root>/testb.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

Which seems to be related to Cocoa [(here)](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1791) or CoreGraphics [(here)](http://support.revealapp.com/kb/known-issues/linker-errors-apple-mach-o-linker-error-_cfhttpmessageappendbytes-referenced-from) (which I also believe is the successor to Cocoa). So how would I solve this? Do I need to include the framework CoreGraphics and if so, how? (simply adding the flag *-framework CoreGraphics* results in *clang: error: unknown argument: '-framework CoreGraphics'* unfortunately)

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

To your first problem: If your enum and function are defined as

```
//YYY.h
namespace Foo{
  enum Bar {bar1, bar2};
  void do_it(Bar bar);
}
```

then you need to import the enum-values in cython along with enum-type-name and it should look like:

```
cdef extern from 'XXX/YYY.h' namespace 'Foo':
    ctypedef enum Bar:
      bar1
      bar2
    cpdef void do_it(Bar a)
```

Then it can be called via `do_it(bar1)` or `do_it(bar2)` somewhere in your cython code. Actually, I learned it from [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990126/how-to-define-in-cython-an-external-c-function-which-has-input-parameters-as-e) some time ago, so you may consider to up-vote it.

The second problem is that you need to link against the juce-library (right now you only use the includes), for this you need to add the following to your Extension-setup:

```
Extension('testb', ['src/JUCE/testb.pyx'], ...
          libraries=[juce],#here the right name on your system
          library_dirs=[PATH_TO_JUCE_LIB_ON_YOUR_SYSTEM]
         }
```

PS: If you don't like the results with the inplace-option, please consult [distutils-documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html) for the alternatives.

**Edit**: JUCE has some further dependencies which need to be provided to the linker. I think the best way is to build one of the c++-examples (e.g. [HelloWorld](https://github.com/WeAreROLI/JUCE/tree/master/examples/HelloWorld)) for your system and to see which  libraries are needed.

By looking into the [Makefile on Linux](https://github.com/WeAreROLI/JUCE/blob/master/examples/HelloWorld/Builds/LinuxMakefile/Makefile) it seems as if at least the following libraries are needed: `freetype2 libcurl x11 xext xinerama webkit2gtk-4.0 gtk+-x11-3.0`. Maybe you even need to install them first, I don't think they are default on every system.

Then your setup should look like:

```
Extension('testb', ['src/JUCE/testb.pyx'], ...
          libraries=['juce', 'x11', 'freetype2', ...], #all needed libraries
          library_dirs=[PATH_TO_JUCE, '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib', ...] #all needed library paths
         }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it seems to have solved my issue with the enums. It also seems to offer a solution for my other problem, but despite my best efforts I'm still having trouble with it. Could you give me some more details?

I have a JuceHeader.h (as seen in the OP) which in turn imports a lot of other headers, and I have the JUCE-library in a *.a-file. How would I then use this is Cython? Simply filling in libraries and library_dirs results in the same error.

The strange part is that the compilation goes fine, and I only get a Symbol not found-error during the importing.

Comment: @meme could you provide your exact setup and the exact error message? Are you sure the missing symbol is provided by the library?

Comment: Thank you, I got a lot (?) further, but I'm running in a related issue (which is extended upon below). Do you know what might cause this?